# Schengen visa proof of accommodation

Tags: visas, schengen, proof-of-accommodation

I need to obtain a Schengen visa for my Europe trip, and am applying at Italian Embassy. In the document check list, they have specified:

**Confirmed itinerary detailing travel plan along with reservation of return or round trip ticket. Under certain circumstances, the Consulate General reserves the right to ask for prepaid tickets. If the applicant will visit more than one Schengen country, means of transportation to those countries must be provided.**

**Proof of accommodation for the entire stay in the Schengen area. All bookings must be made in the applicant’s name, otherwise the person who made the booking needs to produce a written statement in English (dated, signed and accompanied by Photo ID) to confirm that the applicant is covered in the bookings provided.**

I booked my tour partly through a travel counselor/agent, who planned visits to three countries for me. I paid him portion of the total tour cost, and was issued an itinerary. The agent said that the itinerary is sufficient for visa application purposes. It is a PDF document issued under their company logo and has each of the hotel names I am staying in, check in and check out dates.

*Is it sufficient for visa purposes according to above criteria, or do they need individual hotel reservation printouts from each hotel booked?*

I was told I would be receiving those details just 4 weeks before the departure, when I pay the balance due. I am planning to apply for the visa in May.

I am also visiting Paris, which I booked myself and for that I will have a reservation confirmation from a hotel via booking.com.

My concern is about reservations in the countries covered by tour, because the only booking proof I have is PDF itinerary provided to me by the travel agent.

Comment: It's down to how well they know/trust your agent. Based on what you wrote and all other things being equal, your evidence seems fine

Comment: @GayotFow Thanks for the reply. Yes the agent is a reputed company in melbourne. if visa officers have doubts, trust they would go to the next step of confirming the details with the agent without refusing it?
Also for the part of the tour where iam booking myself, reservation confirmation from web sites like booking.com is acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

As @GayotFow has said, what you have provided should be sufficient evidence, according [to the FAQs the French Consulate (San Francisco)](http://www.consulfrance-sanfrancisco.org/spip.php?article2692) site. Your separate booking.com confirmation is acceptable; just make sure that it has shows the complete hotel information (address, telephone, email, web site) and your reservation dates (check in/check out).

As excerpted (with numbers, for easy reference):

> (9.)   Your **travel itinerary**: you MUST BOOK your airline ticket but do not purchase until the visa has been approved.
>
> (11.)  Proof of accommodation:
>    - **Confirmed hotel reservations** for your entire stay in the Schengen states
>    - or a **letter from your travel agent** stating that you are part of a tour.